# Comparing between SN2 and E2

Tags: halides, nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

**Question**
I am confused between the questions B. And C. The earlier is SN2 and later is E2. But what makes the difference?[image]

Comment: Look at the transition state in SN2. How likely (energy barrier?) is an inversion in C)?

Comment: It is pretty clear that you can't perform any kind of elimination in B due to valency constraints, it has to be SN2. For C,you can look at the chair form and decide

Comment: B seems more likely to be $\mathrm{S_N1}$, in C won't we require high temperature for $\mathrm{E_2}$ to occur?

Comment: @Zenix Oops yes, I made a slip up,it should be SN1 for C

Comment: @YusufHasan Bro, shouldn't SN1 be for B?

Comment: With methoxide and benzyl chloride, the substitution is more likely to be bimolecular. Regular solvolysis of benzyl halides is on the border between the two mechanisms.

Comment: @Zhe Won't argue with aikido player ;) how did you then decide between two, when it's on borderline?

Comment: I didn't. Solvolysis would be in methanol, without methoxide. Since methoxide is better at SN2, I think we're breaking the tie.

Comment: For B you get a benzylic cation in a protic solvent. Surely SN1 would be favoured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important factor in these reactions are *nucleophiles*. Here, the use of strong base ([Sodium methoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_methoxide)) in both of the reactions favors the bi-molecular mechanisms ($\ce{S_N2}$ and $\ce{E2}$).

Now, the second factor would be degree of *halogen-linked carbon*. Lower degree carbons ($\ce{\text{deg.} < 2}$) favor $\ce{S_N2}$, while higher degree favors $\ce{E2, E1, S_N1}$. So, $\ce{S_N2}$ is favored in first and $\ce{E2}$ in second.

Temperature conditions and nature of solvent are least important factors, and should be looked up when above two factors are similar.